# Is it mandatory to support filled, snapped and portrait views in Windows 8 Apps?

Tags: windows-8

Do I have to support all these views in Windows 8 Apps? Or could I also develop applications only in Horizontal?

Comment: You need to support all views, but you are also allowed to say that your application [prefers landscape mode if available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230259.aspx#ApplicationUI).

Comment: Portrait view is not required. We released app without it without any issues. Snap view is required, but it could be as simple as flat filled rectangle with icon. Basically as long as snap view doesn't crash your app you'll be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same question I am having few days back, after some googling I found that
Windows 8 App Certification Section 3.6 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx  they mention that " Your app must support a snapped layout. In landscape orientation, your app’s functions must be fully accessible when the app’s display size is 1024 x 768. Your app must remain functional when the customer snaps and unsnaps the app "
So I think all this views are compulsory but you can do one thing like

- use a simple splash screen as your snap view (same like the default Windows 8 Store app)
- and for other views like Fill, Portrait and Landscape you'll define the liquid design layout.
  so that you'll don't have to worry for all the views.